# Cordova/PhoneGap: Linker Error after installing calendarPlugin

Tags: ios, cordova, plist

Ive just installed the calenderPlugin for Cordova iOS from here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/CalendarPlugin

I followed the instructions and drop the m and h files into the plugins folder, then added the key value paris in the cordova.plist file

But when I run the app I get a linker error. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered why this was occurring. I needed to also install the EventKit and EventKitUI frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the xcode icon, then you should see the project icon and
the target icon. click on the target icon, then click build phases.
Click the dropdown for "Link Binary with libraries. Click the plus
sign at the bottom of the window, then search for both frameworks. Add
both of those frameworks, rebuild the project and run it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/ylTBtmq30xg